# Issue: Vim scrolls when cursor is moved

Tags: scrolling, mouse, debugging

I'm not exactly sure what triggers this behavior, but my vim randomly starts scrolling in response to cursor movement (mouse and touchpad). It always scrolls down. Restarting the terminal restores the behavior to scroll only on mousewheel or 2 finger scroll. The terminal itself could be the issue, but I'm not sure how I should go about figuring out the source of the problem.

I have `mouse=a`

Terminal: alacritty

Appreciate any help!

Comment: "Terminal: alacritty"

Comment: @romainl sorry?

Comment: Alacritty has been causing lots of issues to Vim users since the beginning so seeing it mentioned in the context of some weird cursor behavior is not surprising at all. Anyway, you can try two things: a) in Alacritty, start Vim without your config and see if the problem persists, `$ vim -Nu NONE`, b) in a different terminal emulator, start Vim with your config and without (as in a).